# How to decompose a map in cell?

Tags: mapping, gis, computational-geometry

After been able to calculate shortest distance using Dijstra algorithm feeding manually vertex point (getting lat and long from google maps) I'm searching a more dynamic way to do the same.
Assuming I'm having a shape file representing my map (with boundaries and obstacles) which algorithm I can use to decompose it?
Googling a little bit I found I should do a "cell decomposition" but honestly I've not figured out how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have obstacles in shape file, than you could construct visibility graph, and use dijkstra on that.

If you have regions with different passabilities, than you should use some more complicated techniques, for example overlay it with some grid(rectangualr or triangular), than triangulate, assign weights to it's edges, and than use dijkstra too